# Spring security: How to make annotation based role specifications have precedence over pattern-based role specifications

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to combine role-based annotations and pattern-based authorization configuration.

I want the the pattern-based authorization to be the "fallback in case no annotation is specified".

An example of an annotated method endpoint:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping(
  method = RequestMethod.POST,
  headers = "Accept=application/json",
  path="publicApi/doWork" )
public void doWork() {
  ...
}
```

And my pattern-based authorization configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
// specifies actuator endpoints should be secured by this config
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private void configureEndpointRoles(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().
      antMatchers(anonymousUrlPatterns()).permitAll().
      antMatchers("/publicApi/**").access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
      anyRequest().denyAll();
    ;
  }
}
```

Here's how I want the to work:

- If an endpoint URL matches any of the "anonymousUrlPatterns" - permit.
- If an endpoint matches the "publicApi" pattern and is annotated with `@PreAuthorize`, use the definition in the annotation to decide if the user can access it (in this case the user needs either ADMIN or USER role).
- If an endpoint matches the "publicApi" pattern but is not annotated, then the user must have ADMIN role in order to access it.
- If the endpoint matches none of the above - deny.

How would I go about defining this behaviour?

With the above setup as specified, the pattern-based configuration takes precedence and the endpoint invocation is denied (I'm not sure if the pattern-based configuration is taking precedence or if Spring is combining them somehow?)

Spring version - 4.2.3

---

Update: I've tried updating the EnableGlobalMethodSecurity to:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true,
  order = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
```

But that didn't seem to change the behaviour.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible. Maybe you can wrote a subclass of [`GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration.html) and return a custom [`MethodSecurityMetadataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/method/MethodSecurityMetadataSource.html). But you can't configure your default in web security, you have use another source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment from @dur, it looks like you can't do this with a basic configuration.

Under the default Spring Security [AccessDecisionManager](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/AccessDecisionManager.html) strategy, the "No" vote from the pattern-based rule will cause the overall invocation to be denied.

It looks like the behaviour I want will involve writing some custom decision manager logic, something like: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-voter